# Embedded browser control does not display

Tags: blackberry

Basically I embedded a browser into my application. However the request I want to view (google) does not show in the application despite my code linking to it. Any ideas?

```
BrowserFieldConfig myBrowserFieldConfig = new BrowserFieldConfig();
         myBrowserFieldConfig.setProperty(BrowserFieldConfig.NAVIGATION_MODE,BrowserFieldConfig.NAVIGATION_MODE_POINTER);
         BrowserField browserSession = new BrowserField(myBrowserFieldConfig);
                     //browserSession.
         browserSession.requestContent( "http://www.google.com" );
         add(browserSession);**
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It need MDS service to be running. Check for MDS. it will work.

Comment: Ok where can I check for that?

Comment: find MDS folder C:\EclipseBB6.0\plugins\net.rim.ejde.componentpack4.5.0_4.5.0.28\components\MDS.. and then double click on run.bat. that's all. it will start MDS. then you can retest your app.